# How to upload photos to Firebase Storage using Unity SDK for Android?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I have developed one mobile app using Firebase SDK on Unity.

And It's authentication and database works well.

Now I try to upload user's photo to Firebase Storage.

But I can't find the Firebase Storage SDK for Unity.

How can I do this?

Comment: consider just using Parse (ie, back4app.com) - it's also incredibly easy, and you can store all you want.  Firebase is great too but Parse is a little easier

Comment: @JoeBlow Parse is going down very soon.

Comment: HI @AbAppletic !  **Parse is now BACK4APP.com**, it's identical. It is equally as free, etc, for small users. Pretty much everyone that was on Parse is now on back4app.  Sorry if I didn't highlight that in my first comment.  Most people just say "Parse" meaning "back4app".  (Like, if you say "AWS" ... of course that means "on Amazon".)

Comment: The bottom line is DevFanzhi can click to http://back4app.com (ie, "Parse") and achieve what they want in 30, 40 seconds.  Couldn't be easier.

Comment: @JoeBlow Sad... If I knew that was there I wouldn't have used Firebase which has lots of missing features and bugs. Too late now

Comment: Why too late?  It takes maybe 10 minutes to set up and change to back4app - enjoy!

Comment: HI @JoeBlow, it's too late to change all works to use Parse. Can I use Parse and Firsebase in one Project. For example, i maintain all works(such as, database, authentication) with firebase , and then upload photo to Parse Server. Is it possible? Sorry my poor english.

Comment: " it's too late to change all works to use Parse"  I don't really understand that.  it might take 30 minutes to change, and 5 minutes to change each data call. Anyway - good luck!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Currenly, there is no Firebase Storage SDK for Unity, but only for:

1. Android
2. iOS
3. and Web

[image]

However, there are some features. Read more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup)